# Is it possible to retrieve user information through google plus SignIn without including Google Script

Tags: java, javascript

I tried to retrieve Google user's Name and email details by using OAuth2.0 by including their source script

- https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js
- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js

But how to get user's info without including these source scripts in my jsp page.I am a beginner,so I need a detailed explanation for this.

Is it possible to retrieve the information without using third party's(Google's) Source scripts?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use script in your view, you can use Google api client for java and fecth the user's info.

Here is the of documentation for detailed info.

[Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/)